# Python: Splitting a query result with reused delimiter

Tags: python, parsing, split, delimiter

In Python, I need to parse a tab delimited file that stores data in a **question:answer;question:answer** format where you can have one or more question:answer pairs to a date

Unfortunately, if there are multiple answers for a question, the semicolon is *also* used, but only to delimit the answer portion. The question doesn't get repeated.

For example:
**question1:answer1; question2:answer1;answer2;answer3; question3:answer1;answer2**
I would like to split this out to:
question1:answer1
question2:answer1
question2:answer2
question2:answer3
question3:answer1
question4:answer2

What I have right now, only splits on the semicolon, so, it doesn't work

```
with open('QA.txt', 'w', newline='') as tsv:
tsv.write("date\tQ:A\r\n")

for row in cursor:
    date = str(row[0])
    qa = str(row[1])


    if qa.count(';') == 0:
        tsv.write(
            date + '\t' + qa + '\r\n')
    else:
        b = qa.split(";")
        for c in range(0, qa.count(';')+1):
            tsv.write(date + '\t' + b[c] +'\r\n')
```

Cursor contains the results of a query that pulls a timestamp and a string that contains one or more question:answer pairs
Example:
question : answer ; question : answer ; answer;
question : answer
question : answer ; answer ; question : answer
question : answer ; question : answer ; answer ; answer ; answer ; question : answer ; answer
question : answer
question : answer
Essentially, the problem is that each question:answer pair is delimited with a semi-colon. But, if there is more than one answer, the answers themselves are *also* delimited with a semicolon. 
There's no telling on a row how many pairs there will be, or, for any question, how many answers there will be. 
Here's an actual line of data
2017-04-10 10:29:32.183  Gastrointestinal WDL: Yes, Except For; Abdomen Description: Tender;Distended;Round; Bowel Sounds: Hypoactive; Nausea: No

Out of that should come
2017-04-10 10:29:32.183  Gastrointestinal WDL: Yes, Except For
2017-04-10 10:29:32.183  Abdomen Description: Tender
2017-04-10 10:29:32.183  Abdomen Description: Distended
2017-04-10 10:29:32.183  Abdomen Description: Round
2017-04-10 10:29:32.183  Bowel Sounds: Hypoactive
2017-04-10 10:29:32.183  Nausea: No

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code example.  I couldn't see what your cursor variable was storing, so I created it myself at the top.

```
cursor = [['20170501', 'question1:answer1'], ['20170502', 'question2:answer1;answer2;answer3'],
          ['20170503', 'question3:answer1;answer2']]

with open('QA.txt', 'w', newline='') as tsv:
    tsv.write("date\tQ:A\r\n")

    for row in cursor:
        date = str(row[0])
        qa = str(row[1])

        qas = qa.split(":")

        question = qas[0]
        answers = qas[1]

        for answer in answers.split(";"):
            tsv.write(date + '\t' + question + ':' + answer + '\r\n')
```

This creates the following output in QA.txt:

```
    date    Q:A
20170501    question1:answer1
20170502    question2:answer1
20170502    question2:answer2
20170502    question2:answer3
20170503    question3:answer1
20170503    question3:answer2
```

Note that I'm assuming you meant "question3:answer2" instead of "question4:answer2" in your desired output.

Comment: Occasionally, your script is creating rows with question:question

Comment: interesting, can you tell me the input that causes that and I can fix it?

Comment: It looks like the issue is when they ask the same question twice. Example, here's the source:<br>score_dt gastro
2015-11-05 02:17:33.000 Gastrointestinal WDL: Yes, Except For;Gastrointestinal WDL: Yes, Except For<br><br>What comes out of that is <br>2015-11-05 02:17:33 Gastrointestinal WDL:  Yes, Except For<br>
2015-11-05 02:17:33 Gastrointestinal WDL: Gastrointestinal WDL<br>

Comment: And thanks Nick. I added some source info to the original question above as well.

Comment: okay, thanks for clarifying.  That is more complicated. :)  I'd tried to modify it, but I don't think you can really use splits.  You'd have to use a Scanner-type class (Java) in Python to get the next token (whether it's an answer or a question), but I don't know of one.  So you'd have to just do it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using a list of tuples and sublists:

As another user already mentioned in their answer, we do not know exactly what your file structure looks like, therefore, my answer below just uses a string assigned to variable 'entry' for ease of following my parsing scheme. This code works and all you would need to do is reassign 'entry' as opening your file using .readlines(), then  just iterate over the input file list  using a for loop.

```
 # let's take an example entry from the tab delimited file
entry = 'date\tquestion1:answer1; question2:answer1;answer2;answer3; question3:answer1;answer2'

parse1 = entry.split('\t')
date = parse1[0]

qa = parse1[1]

# split by the whitespace
parse2 = qa.split(' ')

# Create an empty list to concatenate tuples to
q_tup_lst = []

for i in parse2:

    parse3 = i.split(':')
    q_tup = ((parse3))
    q_tup_lst.append(q_tup)


new_lst = []

for j in q_tup_lst:

    parse4 = j[1].split(';')

    if '' in parse4:
        parse4.pop()
        new_lst.append((j[0], parse4))

    else:
        new_lst.append((j[0], parse4))

for nn in new_lst:
    for oo in nn[1]:

        print (nn[0] + ':' + oo + '\n')
```